# How to pickup record with smalled date in SYBASE

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

**How to pickup record with smalled date in SYBASE**

I am using the following query;

```
select count(id) as total, 
       convert(date, my_dte, 101) as new_dte
from   my_table
where  convert(date, my_dte, 101) between '05/01/2014' and '05/31/2014'
group by convert(date, my_dte, 101)
order by convert(date, my_dte, 101)
```

Here's the output of this query

```
**total        new_dte**
73             05/02/2014
14             05/06/2014
90             05/19/2014
36             05/21/2014
```

I want to pick up only smallest date record. i am using this query;

```
select max_rec.total
from 
(
select count(id) as total, 
       convert(date, my_dte, 101) as new_dte,
       ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY total ORDER BY new_date DESC ) as rn    
from   my_table
where  convert(date, my_dte, 101) between '05/01/2014' and '05/31/2014'
group by convert(date, my_dte, 101)
order by convert(date, my_dte, 101)
) max_rec
where max_rec.rn = 1;
```

but this is not working it giving me error at **OVER**.

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
**total        new_dte**
73             05/02/2014
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: No one knows how to pick up smallest date record.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just

wrap your original query up as a sub query

Create another sub query that brings back the minimum date value

Perform an inner join on the two sub queries to get the record from the original query that matches the required date